# Trying to get script from object using raycast but raycast is detecting child object instead of parent

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here is the structure of the object getting scanned:

```
PlainTerrain
 UnitPlacementSpot
 PlainTerrainVisual
```

Both PlainTerrain and child object PlainTerrainVisual have a box collider but only the PlainTerrainVisuals box collider is hit.

[Image of the PlainTerrain object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YM7qj.png)
(The green cube object is the PlainTerrainVisual and the invisible box is the PlainTerrain object)

PlainTerrain has a c# script 'PlainTerrain' which is what I am trying to get access to

I have another object that floats over the PlainTerrain object called PlayerSelector that uses a raycast to get the object beneath it.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWjPF.png)

(Dark Blue tile is the PlayorSelector and the green tiles are the PlainTerrain objects)

PlayerSelector script:

```
if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.down), out RaycastHit hitInfo, 1f)) 
        {
            //object underneath 'PlayerSelector'
            Debug.Log(hitInfo.transform.gameObject);
            

        }
```

However when I run the game this is what is printed:

```
PlainTerrainVisual(UnityEngine.GameObject)
UnityEngine.Debug:Log (object)
```

If the raycast is hitting the child object(PlainTerrainVisual) and not the parent object (PlainTerrain) I can't get access to the PlainTerrain script.

Answer (score 0):

Have the parent and child on different layers and setup your raycast so that it only interacts with the parent's layer:

```csharp
public LayerMask layerMask;
/**********/
if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.down), out RaycastHit hitInfo, 1f, layerMask))
```